# Get position of specific element in ordered table

Tags: sql, linq

I have a problem in ranking the players in my database (at least in a way which is good in performance).

I have a single table where all the players are stored. The rank of a player depends on the number of `RankingPoints`. So (in the simplest case) a player's rank is the position in this table ordered by `RankingPoints DESC`.
It may be possible that more than one player have the same `RankingPoints`. Therefore I need a tie-breaker so the rank of players with 200.000 points is not changing.

On the other hand I have some sub-ranks depending on a player's gender, age and nationality.

How can I read the ranks live, e.g. I have a male player, u18 from Germany and I want to know his country-rank.

Currently I have this sub-query for the U18CountryRank

```
U18CountryRank = Players // the database-table holding all players
    .Where(p => p.Gender == MainPlayer.Gender) // male
    .Where(p => p.Country == MainPlayer.Country) // Germany
    .Where(p => p.Classification == MainPlayer.Classification) // U18
    .Where(p => p.RankingPoints >= MainPlayerRankingPoints) // players better or equal than me
    .Where(p => SqlFunctions.Difference(p.PlayerId.ToString(), MainPlayer.PlayerId.ToString()) >= 0) // order by PlayerId
    .Count(); // take the number
```

This is the generated sql:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Players] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE ([Extent2].[RankingPoints] >= [Extent1].[RankingPoints]) AND ([Extent2].[Gender] = [Extent1].[Gender]) AND ([Extent2].[Country] = [Extent1].[Country]) AND ((DIFFERENCE(LOWER( CAST( [Extent2].[PlayerId] AS nvarchar(max))), LOWER( CAST( [Extent1].[PlayerId] AS nvarchar(max))))) >= 0)) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Players] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (cast('b8957470-db27-4b3c-aa5d-3035ca2c86e6' as uniqueidentifier) = [Extent1].[PlayerId])
    )  AS [Project1]
```

which works fine for a single player. But when I need to select all players of a certain nation the performance is going to hell.

I already tried using a `View` which only selects the `PlayerId` as well as the different ranks. Still the performance is lousy on larger sets.

Another approach was using ROW_NUMBER over the ordered sub-set (but still the same problem on larger sets).

What are "best practices" for this kind of problem?

Comment: This seems to be a database issue. You're using SQL-Server? Have you profiled the query and checked the query-plan? Also, you haven't shown the query that you use for multiple players.

Comment: Are you looking for a linq or SQL answer? (Both tags...)

Comment: @TimSchmelter it shows that for a single player 87% are used for an Index Seek (NonClustered) on the player's table.

Comment: @jarlh whatever fits better. So either one is good

Comment: @KingKerosin: but we should help to improve performance of the "whole nation players" query, so show this as well. Currently you're just showing the query that works pretty well.

Comment: I would suggest using a different query for all players that uses `OrderBy` and then you add the rank based on the order.

Comment: What is the actual rank tie-breakers?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would handle finding the sub-rank for male,U18,Germany in `MainPlayer`:

```
var RankOrderedPlayers = Players
                            .Where(p => p.Gender == MainPlayer.Gender) // male
                            .Where(p => p.Country == MainPlayer.Country) // Germany
                            .Where(p => p.Classification == MainPlayer.Classification) // U18
                            .OrderByDescending(p => p.RankingPoints)
                            .ThenByDescending(p => p.PlayerId)
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .Select((p, r) => new { Rank = r+1, p });
```